# How to add a parameter to a LaTeX class via the LyX layout?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I want to have this LaTeX document class code produced by LyX:

```
\documentclass[english]{lni}
```

My Layout class looks like this:

```
#% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
# \DeclareLaTeXClass[lni]{article (LNI)}
# Input general definitions
Input stdclass.inc
```

The custom LNI class defaults to German. It is installed properly and works fine but I get some German output (e.g., "Literatur" instead of "References"). According to the  [LNI guide](http://www.gi.de/service/publikationen/gi-edition-lecture-notes-in-informatics-lni-2005/autorenrichtlinien.html), passing the `[english]` parameter is required for english output.

How do I change it to add the layout file to support the `[english]` parameter?

Comment: Problem solved. No need to deal with it in the layout. Just set Document>Settings>Language>Language package to "Default" instead of "None".